# How to escape forward slash in the matches constraint

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-constraints

How can I escape the forward slashes in the regex when using the matches constraint? This is what I tried:

```
constraints {
    url (
        matches: "^http://www.google.com/$"
    )
}
```

Error: `solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"`

```
constraints {
    url (
        matches: "^http:\/\/www.google.com\/$"
    )
}
```

Error: `unexpected char: '\'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In strings defined with double quotes (`".."`) groovy replaces variables with `$`.

```
def var = "world"
def str = "hello $var" // "hello world"
```

In your validation regex this is causing an error. You want to use the `$` for a regular expression and not for variable replacement. To avoid variable replacement you can define strings in single quotes (`'..'`)

```
def str = 'hello $var' // "hello $var"
```

You don't need to escape `/` when defining the regular expression inside a string but you you should escape `.`. In a regular expression `.` matches any character. So the regular expression `^http://www.google.com/$` matches `http://wwwAgoogleB.com/`.

To escape a character inside a string you have to use `\\` (the first `\` is for escaping the second `\`). So the following expression should work:

```
static constraints = {
    name (
        matches: '^http://www\\.google\\.com/$'
    )
}
```

Normally you could also use the groovy regular expression syntax (`/../`). It this case the regular expression would look like this

```
~/^http:\/\/www\.google\.com\/$/
```

You don't need double backslashes for escaping but therefore you have to escape slashes (because they are used for terminating the regular expression). But as far as I know this syntax does not work with the matches constraint from grails.

Comment: +1. "slashy-string" syntax does work but you don't need the leading `~`. In groovy `/foo/` is just an alternative syntax for string literals. The `~` operator can go in front of any string (single quoted, double quoted or slashy) as a shorthand for `Pattern.compile` to turn the string into a `Pattern`.